# Delegate events to OSM

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, openlayers, openstreetmap

I'm trying to make an image overlay for open street maps. It chould look something like this:

[preview http://www.wildurb.at/urbwalker-app/preview.png](http://www.wildurb.at/urbwalker-app/preview.png)

The Problem im facing is that i can't delegate the events through the transperant area of the image.

Here is the code i tried to use to trigger the events:

```
    <img id="overlay" style="position:absolute;" src="overlay.png"/>
    <div id="map"></div>
```

```
    #overlay {
            position:absolute;       
    }
    #map {
            position:absolute;
            width:300px;
            height:300px;
    }
```

```
    initMap();

    $('#overlay').bind({
            'mousedown' : function(event) {
                    event.preventDefault(); //no image dragging
                    $('#OpenLayers.Map_4_OpenLayers_ViewPort').trigger(event);
            }
    }
    $('#OpenLayers.Map_4_OpenLayers_ViewPort').bind('mousedown', function(event) {
            console.log(event);
    }
```

mousedown is never fired and im not sure which selector to use here
is there a way to pass all events that occur on overlay to the map?

Thanks in advance

best regards chaos

---- edit ---

i created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PQ8gc/2/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found out that one could use pointer-events:none; for chrome firefox and safarie and a workaround with svg for ie and opera

```
var map;

$(document).ready(function() {
    map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');
    layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("Simple OSM Map");
    map.addLayer(layer);

    map.setCenter(
        new OpenLayers.LonLat(-71.147, 42.472).transform(
        new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
        map.getProjectionObject()),
        12
    );

    if($.browser.msie || $.browser.opera) {
        var over = '<svg id="overlay"><image width="300" height="300" xlink:href="overlay.png"></image></svg>';
    } else {
        var over = '<img id="imgOverlay" src="overlay.png"/>';
    }
    $('body').append(over);
});
```

view this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PQ8gc/5/) for working solution

Answer (score 1):

use `bind` api like below . then it trigger mouse down

```
$('#overlay').bind('mousedown',function(event) {
                alert("overlayfired");
                event.preventDefault(); //no image dragging
                $('#OpenLayers.Map_4_OpenLayers_ViewPort').mousedown();
        }
);
```

reference : http://api.jquery.com/bind/

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/KwLce/

Comment: the mousedown is fired on overlay no question, you just used another syntax for binding... but how to delegate it to the underlaying map so it can be zoomed moved and so on

Comment: you have no "OpenLayers" id in your elements

Comment: init map will load the map and should provide a element $('#OpenLayers.Map_4_OpenLayers_ViewPort')

Comment: using the existing event provides properties like pageX which wont be set when using shorthand...